# Automatic Deployment to specific folder

Tags: php, deployment, version-control

I want to automatically deploy my repository changes to my server but I only want to do this so that I can see how the changes will effect the website. So instead of having it update the files users will be using, I would like to instead update it to a folder like test so the devs can go to domain.com/test and see their changes.

The simpler the solution the better, my website isn't really big so i don't need an advanced solution.

Comment: I think you meant a staging server.

Comment: I dont want to create a whole new server though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually mention which version control system that you are using/planning on using but most of them have post commit hooks, by one name or another, that you can tell to check out all changes to a specific location.

Providing you have used relative paths only for all links within your site, *(always a good idea anyway)*, you can just use an unlinked to directory:

If your normal first page is `http://www.MyServer.max/index.html` normally accessed as just `http://www.MyServer.max` and it has several pages and images in a tree that goes:

```
Topdir
 |- index.html
 |- Some images
 |- LinkedDir
     |- etc
```

Then checking out your modified design into a subdirectory called say GobbldyGook so that the site looked like:

```
Topdir
 |- index.html
 |- Some images
 |- LinkedDir
 |   |- etc
 | - GobbldyGook
      |- index.html (new)
      |- Some images (new)
      |- LinkedDir (new)
          |- etc (new)
```

Would give those that knew about it access to the new site as `http://www.MyServer.max/GobbldyGook`

***N.B.** You need to make **sure** that **all** your links within your site are relative links i.e. no paths starting with / for this to work correctly.*

Comment: Thank you! But I've decided to use the service FTPloy.